# Orbital sander papers coming off

Tags: power-tools, sanding

I'm own a Black&Decker orbital sander ([can be found here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004T4W5U6), using hook and loop papers), which is generally a good tool except for the fact that the sanding papers fall off before their sand becomes unusable.

I tried using different paper brands, but same result - paper usually comes off way before it becomes not-sandy. Anything I'm missing? Or do I need a better sander/papers?

Comment: Are you using hook and loop or adhesive back?

Comment: @JacobEdmond hook and loop (will edit post)

Comment: I would look into replacing your pad with an adhesive-back compatible one. Hook and loop pads wear out, and are inherently less reliable at keeping the paper on over time. The other benefit, in my experience, is if you are buying all adhesive back sand paper, you can use it on makeshift sanding blocks, where hook and loop paper only sticks to hook and loop.

Comment: Embarrassing question: are you sure you're affixing the right side of the disk to the sander? First time I used one, I somehow managed to get it backwards and spent longer than I like to admit wondering why the sandpaper wasn't cutting and kept falling off.

Comment: I’m having the same issue. It can’t be that the pad is worn because it’s brand new. First time use. The disc was fine for about 15 minutes and then flew off and won’t stick any more. Replaced the pad, same thing. All holes properly lined up. It’s a Makita M9204.

Comment: Yeah... Mine does this and its brand new

Comment: It is beyond me why everywhere I search the pad is blamed. If the pad was damaged it wouldn't hold a new sanding disk. But it does hold new disks! Until the back of the disk is warn.
Is it just me like that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Be sure to check whether the hooks (part of the hook-and-loop) on the backing pad are intact (not melted) and not clogged, all the way out to the edge of the pad. Usually the hooks around the edge become damaged first. If this is the case, you will need to replace the backing pad or the sander. It looks like replacement parts for your model are readily available online.

If you find that you are regularly burning up the hooks on your sander's pad, try turning down the speed if your sander has a speed control.  I burned through 2 or 3 sanding pad attachments for my oscillating tool before realizing this.  Also try connecting a vacuum or dust extractor to the sander to help get more airflow for cooling, as well as helping to prevent the paper from becoming clogged and overheating.  Or, as Jacob Edmund suggested in a comment on your original question, you may be able to replace the backing pad with a smooth one designed for use with adhesive-backed sandpaper.

Comment: I don't have a speeds on my sander :/

Answer (score 11):

It sounds like you need to replace the pad on your sander.  This is the "hook" part of the hook and loop system.  This is a typical point of failure for orbital sanders, so it should be fairly easy to find one.

If you find you are going through them frequently (in addition to the steps in Rob's answer) you should consider using a "pad protector".  This is just a two-sided sheet with "hooks" on one side and "loops" on the other.  They are made for mesh sandpaper where the hooks are destroyed under normal use by poking through the mesh and contacting the workpiece.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use different paper or replace the bottom pad with a smooth one for adhesives. You just need a replacement pad. A search for "Black & Decker 5" replacement pad" will show you what you need. You can buy them at hardware stores that carry Black & Decker or online.

If you look at the bottom of your sander you will see the 8 dust holes but you will also see a few holes that to down to screws. You can unscrew them and remove the bottom pad and screw the new one on.

You can avoid damaging your new one in many ways, many said already, including minimizing heat and pressure. But the most important thing to do is **align the dust holes on the pad with the holes on the paper**. The downside of this is you need to get sandpaper that has holes that align, probably brand specific. But anytime you leave a hole on the paper over the pad's hooks, you will be sanding down those hooks as if there was no paper on.