# Hook and Loop sandpaper won’t stay on

Tags: power-tools

I have an older DeWalt random orbital sander that I have recently replaced the hook Velcro pad. However within under 15 minutes of use brand new sandpaper disc delaminate - that is to say their loops remain attached to the sander’s hook pad but delaminate from the backing of the sandpaper disc itself, if you see what I mean.

In other words the Velcro is holding, the pads themselves are pulling apart. What’s up with that? (I am not abusing the sander either)

I have reviewed [Orbital sander papers coming off](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/5008/orbital-sander-papers-coming-off) but that seemed to be the loop part detaching from the hook part which is not the case here.

Any thoughts? Cheap sandpaper? Is that even a thing?

Comment: Is this happening across brands/packages or within one package of paper? What are you sanding?

Comment: Sounds like a manufacturing defect with the sandpaper. Return it if possible.

Comment: Could be a manufacturing defect (bad batch, or just cheap crap) but old stock could easily account for this, abrasives are known to decay in various ways — paper becomes more brittle, glue lets go of abrasive grains, seams on belts come apart etc.

Comment: I'll check the brand but I think it's common across multiple brands. I'm starting to suspect I'm letting the sander get too hot, which is causing the delamination. By taking more frequent breaks, I'm seeing less of it. Wonder if it's related.

Comment: The glues they use on these consumables seems to be very sensitive to temperature and age. I can't quite picture the problem you are having, but you might have luck re-attaching the glued edges with a spray contact adhesive, like 3M 77.

Comment: If you think it is a heat issue and you have a variable speed sander, you may try reducing the speed to see if that helps prevent adhesive from breaking down between the loop layer and sandpaper layer.